# Spring OAuth 2.0 - How to validate redirect_uri?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring OAuth 2.0, and I want to protect my application against URL redirect attack. Is there a way to validate the redirect URL at the authorization server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authorization server should only perform a redirect if the `redirect_uri` matches the one registered by the client. So there shouldn't be any need for you to perform a separate check.

If in doubt, try sending an authorization request with a completely different `redirect_uri` and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But how the authorization server check that the redirect_uri matches the one registred by the client ?

Comment: If you want top know the details, you can always [take a look at the code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/DefaultRedirectResolver.java#L112).

Comment: Yes, so according to the source code, the authorization server must implement this method to check whether the requested redirect URI matches the specified redirect URI using this method : redirectMatches(String requestedRedirect, String redirectUri)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. That is the default implementation.

Comment: FYI: Sadly cannot validate per domain only. 
From the code OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationValidator:
<pre>
// As per https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-22#section-4.1.3 When comparing client redirect URIs against pre-registered URIs, authorization servers MUST utilize exact string matching.</pre>

Answer (score 0):

Should be implemented `ClientDetailsService` class and configure registered redirect uri's.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CustomClientDetailsService implements ClientDetailsService {

    @Override
    public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId) {

        String registeredRedirectUris; // Get registeredRedirectUris

        BaseClientDetails clientDetails = new BaseClientDetails();
        clientDetails.setRegisteredRedirectUri(registeredRedirectUris);

        return clientDetails;
    }
}
```